Sqlalchemy: circular import while implementing foreign key in different files
so I got two files: auth.py and chats.py
The main goal: The two classes in two different files must be bound to each other using foreign key
The main problem: But to do this, foreign key requires me to import files. If I do so, I get into circular import, if I don't, then both classes dont recognize each other.
When I try to bind two classes with foreign key, I got stuck in circular import, since I am importing my classes in both files.
# auth.py:
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Column,
    Integer,
    BigInteger,
    String,
    Text,
    Boolean,
    DateTime,
    ForeignKey,
    Enum,
    Table,
    UniqueConstraint,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
import uuid

from src.settings import settings
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

from .legacy.base_model import BaseModel
from .chats import Admin, Group


class User(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    username = Column(String)
    first_name = Column(String) 
    last_name = Column(String)
    bio = Column(Text)
    avatar = Column(String)
    gender = Column(Boolean)    
    birthdate = Column(DateTime)
    email = Column(String, unique=True)
    password = Column(String)
    phone_number = Column(String)
    live_status = Column(Boolean)
    last_seen = Column(DateTime)
    language = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("locale.id"))

    admins = relationship("Admin", back_populates="user")
    groups = relationship("Group", back_populates="owner")


class Locale(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "locale"

    code = Column(String)       

# chats.py
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Column,
    Integer,
    BigInteger,
    String,
    Text,
    Boolean,
    DateTime,
    ForeignKey,
    Enum,
    Table,
    UniqueConstraint,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker, declared_attr
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
import uuid


from .legacy.base_model import BaseModel
from src.settings import settings
from .auth import User  # here is the main problem, I am importing User here, and 
                        # in auth.py file the Admin class below also was imported

class Admin(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "admins"

    chat_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("channel.id"))
    chat_type = Column(Enum("channel", "group", "direct", name="chat_type_enum"))
    user_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("user.id"))
    admin_name = Column(String)

    channel = relationship("Channel", back_populates="admins")



class Group(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "group"

    owner_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("user.id"))
    title = Column(String)
    code = Column(String)
    member_count = Column(BigInteger)
    description = Column(Text)
    avatar = Column(String)
    visibility = Column(Boolean)

    owner = relationship("User", back_populates="groups")


class Subscriber(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "subscribers"

    chat_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("channel.id"))
    user_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("user.id"))

    channel = relationship("Channel", back_populates="subscribers")


class Channel(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "channel"

    title = Column(String)
    description = Column(Text)
    code = Column(String)
    avatar = Column(String)
    member_count = Column(BigInteger)
    owner_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("user.id"))

    admins = relationship("Admin", back_populates="channel")
    subscribers = relationship("Subscriber", back_populates="channel")

and I also have BaseModel class which was bound to declarative base and gives some basic default columns for all of my tables:
from sqlalchemy import String, UUID, Column, DateTime, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column, Mapped
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
import uuid

from src.db.orm.config import SessionLocal
from src.db.orm.config import Base
from src.logger import logger


class BaseModel(Base):
    """
    This class serves as a base model for all other database models in the application.
    It provides common fields such as id, created_at, updated_at, and status.

    Attributes:
    - id (UUID): Unique identifier for each record.
    - created_at (DateTime): Timestamp indicating when the record was created.
    - updated_at (DateTime): Timestamp indicating when the record was last updated.
    """

    __abstract__ = True

    id = Column(UUID, default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=True, default=func.now())
    updated_at = Column(
        DateTime, nullable=True, default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now()
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("Please implement the description of the table")
    

    def save(self):
        """Save the instance to the database."""
        try:
            session = SessionLocal()
            session.add(self)
            session.commit()
            logger.info("Saved successfully")
            return self
        except Exception as e:
            session.rollback()
            raise e

But if I dont import them, they wont recognize each other. I am really wondering that do I have a chance to just assign it like I assign in django, like this: src.db.orm.auth.User inside the Admin class and vice versa.
Any advice or help is strongly appreciated.
I tried to import both files to each other, but got into circular import.
